# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 - Create Plug-in screen

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I am sure this will be possible but I cannot find any tutorials or instructions.

I want to create my own screen (using C#) that can be called from a new menu option within Dynamics so that as far as the user is concerned they are just using another "Dynamics screen" rather than a custom built one.

Is this feasible..? Does anyone know of a good tutorial for this..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define "own screen".  Do you just want to link to another webpage?

Comment: By "own screen" I meant creating a new page that I can build my own logic into, and have that page be accessible to the user via a Dynamics custom menu option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "own screen (using C#)" you mean an ASP.NET web page:

1. Add an IFRAME to the CRM Form.
2. Add a button to the ribbon of this form and hook this into a JavaScript function on the form.
3. Set the src of the IFRAME to the "screen" you wish to display.

Download the SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24004) and have a **good** read.  It also includes some excellent example code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and supported method of meeting this requirement, including C#, is to create Silverlight resource and deploy it to CRM as WebResource. Either embed the resource in a form set as hidden and then show it in response to a button click on the ribbon. You can also place the Silverlight WebResource on a HTML page, also deployed as WebResource and pop it up in a modal window using JavaScript based on a ribbon button click.

Recommend [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-create-a-silverlight-web-resource-that-interacts-with-crm-2011-forms.aspx) to get you started.